Defective third-party booking - what action to take?
I booked a ticket through eDreams who usually gives me a fictitious email address to use. For the first time ever, that email address didn't match with what Ryanair has for the booking.
As eDreams washed their hands, merely telling me to check in at the airport (I told them there's a hefty fee, but I seriously might as well have been talking to the wall), I contacted Ryanair, who of course would provide zero assistance without the correct email address...which is precisely what I don't know.
I made a second identical booking, and this time the email address I was given was correct and I've already added the booking to my myRyanair account.
So I've now emailed Ryanair's customer service director and the Ryanair Fraud Department explaining the situation in detail AND attaching screenshots of my chat with eDreams. I asked for a refund of the first, defective booking, and then asked whether, in case they won't do this, they'd be OK with me doing a chargeback against eDreams, seeing as chargebacks against Ryanair results in a temporary ban from future travel until the funds are repaid.
My questions are: if I don't get any helpful reply from anyone at Ryanair, can I do a chargeback against eDreams without Ryanair then blocking me from travel?
Secondly, if I cannot safely do a chargeback, whom do I take to court? eDreams for failing to give me the correct email address, or Ryanair for refusing to work with me in any way whatsoever to access my booking?
UPDATE: the Ryanair Fraud Department got back to me and agreed to refund the defective booking.

Who did you pay, eDreams or Ryanair?

@Arno eDreams..

That's why you should always book directly with the airline. Saving a few bucks is not worth the customer service hell your exposing yourself to.

@Hilmar The saving becomes a lot over time given how often I fly (basically every week). Besides I've never had the generated email address be wrong before, ever

I’m surprised a seasoned traveller like you uses OTAs rather than booking direct with the airlines, especially with Ryanair who are quite clear on the fact that they don’t want people to book via third parties and consider OTAs to be the scum of the Earth. What was the point of booking via eDreams? Surely it can’t have been cheaper? Do you have the PNR? Did you try the verification procedure?

@jcaron eDreams/Opodo are normally EUR 7-12 cheaper for Ryanair flights, GBP 5-8 cheaper for easyJet flights and up to EUR 23 cheaper for Jet2.com flights, which as I said becomes a lot over time. I always get the PNR and fictitious email address and use those to verify on ryanair.com with zero issues. The problem now, which has never happened before, is that eDreams gave me the wrong fictitious email address and are flat-out refusing to even investigate it. Without the right email address I can't access the verification and so can only travel if checking in at the airport for EUR 55

@Crazydre I have to admit I don’t understand how they can sell a flight cheaper than the airline when they are buying it from the Ryanair website. Ryanair even name them the #1 OTA pirate… also tried a few RYR flights and eDreams wouldn’t even find them. I’m puzzled…

@jcaron based off the link article they make money by overcharging for other services like a seat reservation

@jcaron "Ryanair who [...] consider OTAs to be the scum of the Earth." Talk about a pot calling a kettle black!

@TripeHound I know right? Just like when Ana Pastor (head of the Ryanair Immigration Department) dissed TIMATIC to me on the phone for having plenty of inaccuracies. While true, her department has NO high ground given the amount of misinterpretations they make (and refuse to let themselves be proven wrong). FFS, even a Ryanair crew member told me about them "yeah, they're not the best"

If eDreams is at fault here (and you have evidence of that) you can probably raise a chargeback with then for service not provided.   Ryanair shouldn't be affected by this, because you didn't pay them, eDreams did.
If it is within the timeframe, you could initiate the chargeback only after you have already flown, this way you are sure that eDreams doesn't cancel other tickets you booked with them.

What would be sufficient evidence of eDreams being at fault? Will the eDreams booking confirmation (showing the generated email address) do combined with the Ryanair chat where the agent confirms that's not the email address they have?

I don't know, and I'm not a lawyer. But, if that prevents you from traveling I would assume it is enough evidence.

Thanks, been resolved now! :)

@Crazydre How did you motivate the presumably good result?

@DavidRecallsMonica I told them as it is and the Ryanair Fraud Department told me they'd refund the first-defective booking
